# Hbase Single Query to Return all the column from Multiple Column Family

Tags: java, hbase

Iam new to the Hbase. I would to like to know how to retrieve all the columns from two column family in Single Query using Java API, and please provide me the link which will give the brief about Hbase internal architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adding multiple column families with "addFamily" method.

```
Get get = new Get(rowKey);
get.addFamily(columnFamily1);
get.addFamily(columnFamily2);
```

(if you use the "scan")

```
Scan scan = new Scan(startRowKey, stopRowKey);
scan.addFamily(columnFamily1);
scan.addFamily(columnFamily2);
```

And about the document, you can find everything in hbase book which in the hbase website. 
https://hbase.apache.org/2.0/book.html